# VS Code - PHP All autocomplete

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I used Sublime Text, but VS Code seems to me more modern and it is open source, so I want to use it.

I have a problem with VS Code: I can not get autocomplete with PHP.

For example with Sublime Text, I installed the package "All autocomplete". This allows me to:

In my editor, if I have my Model "Customer" open, and in my Controller "CustomerController" I do:

```
$Customer->
```

Sublime Text suggests the methods I created in my Model "Customer".

With VS Code I can not do this here. I tested the packages: "PHP IntelliSense" and "PHP Intellisense - Crane" and "PHP Intelephense".
None of these packages solved my problem.

Do you have the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: If installed correctly, "PHP IntelliSense" should do the trick. Read the installation notes here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense

Comment: _Do this ? :
setting php.suggest.basic to false

_I did this:
IN "File > Preferences > Settings > Extensiosn > PHP", I unchecked "PHP › Suggest: Basic",
but it still does not work.

Comment: Is `php.executablePath` also set correctly to a PHP7 installation?

Comment: One my Windows 10 I have (environment variable) C:\wamp3.1\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9

Comment: Try `php -v` in a new command line window

Comment: Ok thank you. The result : PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: Is your controller file referenced correctly in your model? You might need to open your project as a **folder** rather than separate files.

Comment: I use Laravel. I open my project as a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I realized my other extension **All AutoComplete** have conflict with PHP Intelephense. So I disabled **All AutoComplete** extension and worked.